# I want my anchor link to stop right before the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery script that adds an "easing" effect to my anchor links, the only problem is that now I have a sticky nav so when the nav slides to the DIV it hides part of it.

Is there a way to slide the nav until right before the div starts?

Anchor links easing effect:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a').click(function () {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href="#donate">How to donate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#locations">Drop-off locations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#party">Party details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show your implemented HTML?

Comment: I added my HTML @ElliotM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to subtract the height of your header from the scroll calculation. `scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - header.height()`

*note: Here, 'header' refers to whatever html element you are using as your fixed navigation.*

Comment: The jquery stops working if I add that, I just updated my question with the HTML just incase.

Comment: did you replace 'header' with the proper jQuery?

Comment: Did you declare nav or navigation as variables? If not, it won't work like that. works here: http://jsfiddle.net/uakc5/1/.

Answer (score 1):

I will use this code for a single call to action from the top to the desired section (Pure JavaScript)

```
const scrollerBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
const sectionView= document.getElementById('section-view');
var headerHeight = document.getElementById('main-header').offsetHeight;

scrollerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // scroll to your element
    sectionView.scrollIntoView(true);

    // now calculate fixed header
    var scrolledY = window.scrollY;

    if (scrolledY) {
        window.scroll(0, (scrolledY - headerHeight));
    }
})
```